# 7-ZIP, Show extracted files when complete (Like Windows)

Tags: zip, 7-zip, rar

1- Is it possible to show/open the extracted files when extraction completed using 7-ZIP in the context menu and inside the app in Windows GUI? Like the Windows default Zip extractor.

There are some details here (2010) but couldn't notice how to use them and it's a very old topic. https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/b5ddfd22/

2- Second, Can I have the option to "extract the files in the same folder? Something like "Extract to *" in the context menu?

Thanks

Comment: The 7zip context menu has "extract here" which means the current folder.

Comment: You want to to show/open **all** the extracted files?

Comment: @DavidPostill If you mean the first question, yes It has, but it doesn't "open" the extracted files' folder. In Windows, there's a checkbox that open the folder when the extraction completed.

Comment: @harrymc I want to open/show the folder of the extracted file.